# how to delete the database from restfull api using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

please help me to solve this issue

**Model Code**

this is the model section and i want to delete pariticular row from the database but it does't works

```
public function update($id, $data){

       $this->db->where('id', $id);

       if($this->db->update('tbl_books', $data)){

          return true;

        }else{

          return false;

        }

    }
```

**Controller code**

whenever i try to delete the data it shows error,

```
 function deleteBook_delete()
    {

        $id  = $this->delete('id');
        
        if(!$id){

            $this->response("Parameter missing", 404);

        }

         
        if($this->book_model->delete($id))
        {

            $this->response("Success", 200);

        } 
        else
        {

            $this->response("Failed", 400);

        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the CodeIgniter docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data

```
$this->db->delete('tbl_books', array('id' => $id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Write database related code into the model not in controller and use code below to delete row from the table

```
$this->db->delete('table name', array('id' => $id));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->delete('tbl_user', array('id' => $id));
```

or

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);   
$this->db->delete('tbl_user');
```